# Application can't find settings or image files after windows boot

Tags: c#, windows, settings, boot

I have an application which boots after the windows boot. That works well, however the application can't seem to find the necessary csv file with settings or the necessary resources which result in a crash. However application works fine if I manually open it after I log in into my Windows account.

I tried to do a check if the csv file really exists, but as said above, the application can't find it. Since the csv file contains some settings and language data the application cannot run if the file isn't found

Before I read out the csv file, I check if the file exists by doing the following:

```
     try {
        string langFile = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.WorkingDirectory, "languageSupport.csv"); //Get language file
        // Read out the file
    } catch {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not load settings data!");
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured: " + e.Message);
    }
```

Also, I think it is important no note the following: This error only happens when the computer has been turned off for atleast a few hours. A reboot or shutting the pc down and turning it  back on after a few minutes doesn't give me the error.

What can I do to improve this? Why does it crash when it boots automatically and not when I boot it manually?

Comment: Log down the full path whenever your application runs. So you can see where it's actually reading. If the path is right, your file may be lacking permission for whichever user account is running the application.

Comment: @Vlam I will try to do that. One question though, how can the file lack permission if the same user tries to open the application manually or after the user logs into his account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when it load automatically the working directory is different than when you open it manually from the `.exe`, try using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to make sure that paths are relative to your application, also you can use it to specify the .csv file path, assuming that the file is in the same directory as your application:

```
try {
        string langFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "languageSupport.csv"); //Get language file
        // Read out the file
    } catch {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not load settings data!");
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured: " + e.Message);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that this solution is a good one. Yes, it might work but what if the user installs the application in a different folder? That's why I set the WorkingDirectory in the Settings file so the user can install the application anywhere on their device

Comment: @Infiltrator try the updated answer hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks, will try that out. Maybe it's also important to note the following: This error only happens when the computer has been turned off for atleast a few hours. A reboot or shutting the pc down and rebooting it after some minutes doesn't give me the error.

Comment: Good then try it to check that this gives you a consistent behavior

Comment: Seems to work after the first night. Will test this furter, but thanks for this solution!